# Using #undef preprocessor directive

Tags: c, undefined, preprocessor-directive

> Here are the 2 programs with very minor change.

> Practice.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define P (i+j)

main()
{
  int i,j,k=0;
  printf("\nI = ");
  scanf("%d",&i);
  printf("\nJ = ");
  scanf("%d",&j);
  k=P;
  printf("\nValue of Defined Macro P = %d\n",k);

  #undef P
    printf("\nValue of Undefined Macro P = %d\n",k);
}
```

Output of the above program is:

```
I = 5

J = 9

Value of Defined Macro P = 14

Value of Undefined Macro P = 14
```

> New.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define P (i+j)

main()
{
  int i,j,k=0;
  printf("\nI = ");
  scanf("%d",&i);
  printf("\nJ = ");
  scanf("%d",&j);
  k=P;
  printf("\nValue of Defined Macro P = %d\n",P);

  #undef P
    printf("\nValue of Undefined Macro P = %d\n",P);
}
```

Output of the above program is :

```
Practice.c: In function 'main':
Practice.c:15:48: error: 'P' undeclared (first use in this function)
    printf("\nValue of Undefined Macro P = %d\n",P);
                                               ^
Practice.c:15:48: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for eac
h function it appears in
```

Now I want to know that why did `Practice.c` got successfully compiled and executed, where I used variable `k` to display the output, and why did `New.c` displayed error on using Macro Template `P` directly?

Comment: Obligatory: in a "real code", don't do that, ie. use don't use macros like that. It leads to hard-to-find problems, possibly resulting in brain injury, and some unfortunate victims even start to participate in obfuscated C coding competitions. Just say no.

Comment: @hyde If not this way than how can I use it? Can I also use #undef during runtime?

Comment: "Runtime"? Macros are essentially "search-replace" in source code just before actual compilation (at preprocessing stage). They're not functions or variables. So #undef at runtime is about as sensible concept as editing source code at runtime. And to say anything more about the use of macro in question code, it'd be necessary to know *why* you have the macro and *why* do you `#undef` it. Use of macros should always have some good reason (such as, being idiomatic C way to do something, avoiding even more error-prone copy-pasting).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785047/how-can-i-undef-and-def-preprocessor-value-at-run-time

Comment: Why are you using scanf() like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocessor directives are replaced *where they occur*. The variable `k` is set to 14 on the line where you write `k=P` which is exactly equivalent to writing `k=14` so it still has its value after the `#undef`.

Comment: If the format of `Practice.c` is changed to the following-

`#undef
  k=P;
  printf("\nValue of Undefined Macro P = %d\n",k);`
Rest of the program remains the same, than it acts exactly as the `New.c`. 
Is it due to the same reason you explained in the above comment?

Answer (score 2):

`#define` replaces strings in code during compile time. So when the compiler processes

`#define P (i + j)`, it replaces every instance of P that it sees with `(i + j)` until it reaches the point where it reads `#undef P`. This tells the compiler to stop replacing `P` with `(i + j)`.

As a result, the last instance of `P` (after the `#undef` statement) is not replaced, and since there is no variable P declared above in the code, it results to an error.

This was not a problem in the first program since you have already declared `k` in the line

`int i,j,k=0;`

Answer (score 1):

A rule in MISRA is that #undef can make it unclear which macros exist at a particular point within the translation unit. 
Therefore , it is advisory not to use #undef in order not to get such behaviour.